# How can i use isset and switch to call a page

Tags: php, html

Can I ask how can I call a page using isset and switch? This is my code.

```
<a href="?action=Sample-content">Sample</a>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
            switch ($_POST["action"]) {
            case 'Sample-content':
                        require_once("PageContent/Home.php");
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your code looks good. Just add default case to your switch.

Comment: You should be using `$_GET` - not `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <a href="?action=Sample-content">Sample</a>
                    <?php
                        if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
                                switch ($_POST["action"]) {
                                case 'Sample-content':
                                            require "PageContent/Home.php";

                            }
                        }
                    ?>
```

header(Location:"PageContent/Home.php"); this not Require_once

And you can read Documentation of Header in [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

**Update** I miss understood question so i edited to require plus read about this require, include [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_includes.asp)

Dont know whats wrong but its working i have 1.php, 2.php files

1.php have code like this

```
<?php include '2.php'?>
<div>
<span> <?php echo $color, $name ?>
</div>
```

2.php have code like this

```
<?php 
$color='red';
$name='Gary'
?>
```

when i show 1.php output was like this

`redGary`

okey now i tried 2nd test in 1.php i edited to this

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['Test'])){
    switch($_GET['Test']){
        case "Sample-content": 
            $itsworked = 'Its is working see';
            include '2.php';
    }
}
else {
    $itsworked='nah its not working';
}
 ?>
<div>
<span> <?php echo $color, $name , $itsworked?>
</div>
```

and its not working because there was no GET in url beside url was like this (http://localhost:8080/quizPhp/1.php) also out put was like this

```
Notice: Undefined variable: color in C:\xampp\htdocs\quizPhp\1.php on line 15   
Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\quizPhp\1.php on line 15
nah its not working // because those parameter is not declared in 1.php file
```

after this i changed url to give value in `$_GET` like this (http://localhost:8080/quizPhp/1.php?Test=Sample-content) to give value 
output was like this its working

```
redGaryIts is working see
```

Comment: I want to call the page I don't want to goto a apge

Comment: Hmm Call page to show in iframe or what? @KeyBirdPadilla

Comment: This is working but I want to call the page from page content into my index page. not iframe in the div.

Comment: @KeyBirdPadilla i edited `Require "PageContent/Home.php";` this

Comment: @KeyBirdPadilla i edited my answer to see if its working or not also this is working nothing wrong

Answer (score 0):

the problem is simply that you use a link with get params and try to get the page with $_POST.

```
<a href="?action=Sample-content">Sample</a>
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
            switch ($_GET["action"]) {
            case 'Sample-content':
              require "PageContent/Home.php";
              break;
        }
    }
?>
```

this work well. If you want to use $_POST you have to use a form with method="post" to "send" the user from one page to the other, but I think that this is not the best way